# Freezing my app with Fbs/PyInstaller result in fail to execute pyi_rth_qt5plugins when starting on an other pc

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, pyside2, fbs

I'm trying to freeze my python application using Fbs (https://build-system.fman.io/)
After running to some libs error that I fixed I was able to freeze it without any issue. **I can perfectly start the app on my computer**. But on an other computer I will get the error:
`Failed to execute script pyi_rth_qt5plugins`

After some research it seems the problem comes from PyInstaller that fbs is using.
I have no errors in the terminal when freezing but in the *warn-Colorspace_converter.txt* file I have the following errors:

```
missing module named 'PyQt5.QtCore' - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional), l:\script\colour\venvcolour\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt5plugins.py (optional)
missing module named 'PyQt5.sip' - imported by l:\script\colour\venvcolour\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt5plugins.py (optional)
missing module named sip - imported by l:\script\colour\venvcolour\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt5plugins.py (optional)
```

The thing it's that I am using PySide2 so how can I fix that ?

Thread to similar issue that i found but that i didn't understand as they were madded only for pyinstaller or PyQt5. Should i install PyQt5 that may cause issue with fbs to have the two libraries ?

- https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2301
- [Python 3.6.x PyInstaller gives error "No module named 'PyQt5.sip'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324754/python-3-6-x-pyinstaller-gives-error-no-module-named-pyqt5-sip/51330788)

Environment:

- Windows 10
- PySide2
- Python 3.6.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that recreating my virtual environment and downgrading to a lower PySide2 version (5.13.1) fixed the issue.

I still have the same errors in the PyInstaller log (and also have some lib not found in the terminal) but the app can launch perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert or anything.. sharing my experience

You can use the latest Pyinstaller version to freeze the app.. then move the objects to `target/<appname>` folder.
Now use `fbs installer` to make an installer out of it.

`Failed to execute script` always comes up if some dependency is missing.

I believe we can also use `fbs freeze --debug`, which will show the missing dependencies. You can then add them to the `hidden imports` in `.spec` file

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i used `freeze --debug` to fix everything and i managed to get it working on my pc like that (but still not on other pc). I'm going to  try to use PyInstaller instead of Fbs for freezing.